# Javascript doesn't update session, only the page reload does the job

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Sessions are set in the python code. I use flask as a framework. Session username values stay the same until user reloads a page. If there is a way to respond to the changes in session values with javascript or reload the necessary part without reloading the whole page? Thanks.

index.html:

```
<div id="cform">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <div class="cl">{{ session['username'] }}$ >
            <input type="text" class="cli" name="cmd"
            autocomplete='off' value="" autofocus />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function () {
        $('form').last().submit(function () {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_cmd', {
                cmd: $('input[name="cmd"]').last().val()
            }, function (data) {
                var $query = $('input[name="cmd"]').last().val();
                $("<span>{{ session['username'] }}$ > " + $query + "</span><br />").appendTo("#output");
                $(data).each(function (i, val) {
                    $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                        $("<span>" + v + "</span><br />").appendTo("#output");
                    });
                });
                $("#output").append($("form"));
                $("form input").val("").focus();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

index.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  if 'username' in session:
    username = escape(session['username'])
  else:
    session['username'] = 'guest'

  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/_cmd')
def cmd():
  cmd = request.args.get('cmd')
  interpreter = Interpreter(cmd)
  output = interpreter.mediator()
  return jsonify(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Flask, but it seems to me that your are making a mistake there :

```
 $("<span>{{ session['username'] }}$ > " + $query + "</span><br />").appendTo("#output");
```

Here you set your username for good only when user loads the page, and do so even when user's udpate it.

You should be doing something like :

```
  $("<span>"+data[username] + $query + "</span><br />").appendTo("#output");
```

and in your backend, a something like :

```
  def cmd:
    ...
    output[username] = session["username"]
    ...
```